# How can I keep a running total of my die rolls in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Okay, so I've searched everywhere and couldn't find any help with this. I have six different images of a single die. Each time the user clicks the button, the image changes. I need to keep a running total, though, and this is where I'm stuck.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<script>
function displaydie()
{ var total=0;

var num= ("src",(Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1) + ".jpg")

document.getElementById("die").setAttribute("src",(Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1) + ".jpg")
}



</script>

<img id="die" alt="die"/>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="displaydie()"/>

<span id="total"/></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where's the code? What have you tried? Etc.

Comment: You could use an array.

Comment: Would I have to assign a numeric value to the elements in the array, then?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know each roll, use an array.

```
var rolls = [];

//When rolled, do:
rolls.push(<roll value>);
```

If you just need a total, then just add to an integer?

```
var total = 0;

//When rolled, do:
total += <value>;
```

Hard to give a good suggestion without more detail on what you're after.

**edit:**
Ok... it sounds like a project/assignment, so I'll just try to steer you in the right direction.

If all you need to worry about is the total, then there's no need for an array.

You already have the total variable declared, so that's good.

In your `displaydie` function, what I would recommend is that you first declare a variable and assign your random (1-6) number to it.  Then add that number to the total, then use that to set the source of the image.

To display your running total, you'll want to get your "total" span by using it's ID, then set the value (probably via the innerText property) - remove the document.write call that you have.

Sounds like you need to add a "Reset" button to set the total back to 0 as well.

The `for ...` loop is not a timed function - it's going to execute as fast as it possibly can.  So make sure that's what you want, or if you want something like `setTimeout` or `setInterval` instead.  If the for loop **is** what you want, then consider not changing the image source during that, as it's not going to be able to update fast enough to be seen anyway.

Comment: It will be easier to read if you edit your original post and tag it as code (for the formatting and all that).  :)

Comment: I'm so new to Javascript. And this site. :c

Comment: So what is it you're trying to do?  It looks like you're "rolling" the die 5,000 times as soon as the page loads, then also letting the user roll it by clicking a button?  And I'm guessing you want the running total inside of the "total" <span> element?

Comment: I don't even know if it's possible, but I feel like I should create an array and assign a value to each element. Then get the running total.

Comment: Create an application that has a die, singular for dice, on the screen. When you click the die, it will roll and display a number. Keep a running total of each roll. Create a reset button to see the score back to 0. Use images for your dice. And try to simulate a roll with the timer event, for a perfect score.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting bit of code you've got going...  I worked through it to get to understand it, but I'll just give you a few pointers unless you can't get it yourself.

First off, while you work through this you should put in a few checks.  `alert(variable)` is a simple one, although most people prefer using `console.log(variable)`.  If you try `console.log(num)`, you'll find a very interesting result.  You might want to make `num` equal to the dice roll, then put the variable into your `setAttribute`.

Another thing is, `document.write` will completely overwrite everything you have on that page.  Try setting the `value` of your `"total"` `span`.

Now, while I was reading through this, I got the idea that your `for` loop is to test to make sure that the running total is building up.  What you have to understand here is that, when you roll your dice, you're not going to be adding to the total.  You're also not going to be writing the total to your document.  You might want to try adding these into the function so that everything is handled by one click.

If you're really having trouble on it, work a bit more and ask and I'll give you the code I was editing.

Comment: It's a good start. Like the example below shows, total should be outside of the function scope.  That means that it isn't going to be rewritten every time you run the function.  Also, you want the number you're defining to just be a number. "src" and ".jpg" are strings, and are going to change what happens when you start trying to add things together.  "6.jpg" + "6.jpg" = "6.jpg6.jpg", while 6 + 6 = 12.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var total=0;
function displaydie()
{ 
  var diceNumberArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
  var showImageDice = Math.floor((Math.random()*diceNumberArray.length)+1);
  var sideToShow = "Image"+showImageDice;
  total += showImageDice;
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
  document.getElementById("die").setAttribute("src",sideToShow+".jpg");
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<img id="die" alt="die"/>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="displaydie()"/>

<span id="total"/></span>
</body>

</body>
</html>
```